# UNSUBSCRIBE PHP AND SMTP SCRIPT

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

I have a website [Easycryptos](https://easycryptos.org) and I have SMTP configurated. Now I want to have an unsubcription from mailing list. This script must get the email address ($e) and send an e-mail to unsubscribe@easycryptos.org with subject "unsubscribe) and message unsubscribe and email ($e). where "e" is the email address taht received our newsletter and wants to unsubscribe

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");
require("class.smtp.php");

$SenderAddress = "admin@easycryptos.org";
$destinatario= "unsubscribe@easycryptos.org";

$smtpHost = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";  // Dominio alternativo brindado en el email de alta 
$smtpUsuario = "My smtp username";  // Mi cuenta de correo
$smtpClave = "SMTP PASSWORD;  // Mi contraseña


define('OCU_RELEASE', '1.1');
define('OCU_ERR', !empty($_GET['err']));

if (OCU_ERR) {
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
}
else {
  error_reporting(0);
}

if (basename(__FILE__) == '1cu.php') {
  die('For your safety: you should really change the name of this file');
}

if (!empty($_GET['test'])) {
  die("OK: ".OCU_RELEASE);
}

if (empty($_GET['l']) && empty($_GET['e'])) {
  die("OK");
}


$l = isset($_GET['l']) ? $_GET['l'] : '';
$e = isset($_GET['e']) ? $_GET['e'] : '';
$m = isset($_GET['m']) ? $_GET['m'] : '';

$l = OCU_Unencode($l);
$e = OCU_Unencode($e);


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";

$mail->from =($SenderAddress);
$mail->AddAddress($destinatario);
$mail->subject = "Unsubscribe";
$message = "Unsubscribe $e";


switch ($mode) {
  case "1":
      $headers = "X-UserMail: $e";
      break;
  case "2":
      $headers = "From: $from";
      break;
  default:
      $headers = "From: $from" . "\r\n" . "X-UserMail: $e";
}
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
  'ssl' => array(
      'verify_peer' => false,
      'verify_peer_name' => false,
      'allow_self_signed' => true
  )
);

$mail->Send(); 
if (mail($AddAddress, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  Header("Location: removal.htm");
} else {
  die("There was an error processing your request; please manually send an email to $l with Unsubscribe as its subject");
}

exit;

function OCU_Unencode($data) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'));
}
?>
```

Can any one help me to make it work? This code seems to work and redirects to the removal.htm page but no email arrives to the e-mail account for this purpouse( unsubscribe@easycryptos.org).

I have been some tutorials but nothing seems to work, so I decided to come here and ask your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Odd, your setting up phpmailer to send the email but then using `mail()`, you not set $mode, $from or $subject

Comment: My friend I am using it

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";

$mail->from =($SenderAddress);
$mail->AddAddress($destinatario);
$mail->subject = "Unsubscribe";
$message = "Unsubscribe $e";

Comment: sure, but your using `mail()` to send the email, rtm: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer you should have `$mail->send();` in your code

Comment: I have added $mail->send(); as your suggestion but still not working